# Issues with [emulator]

Tags: discussion, tags

I draw your attention to the [emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulator) tag.

The tag wiki (not so clearly) says that this is tag is for questions about (a/the) Android Emulator.

Unfortunately, it's being used for questions about any sort of emulator. (J2ME was the most recent one I saw.)

It seems to me that if nothing else the language in the tag wiki needs to be more specific.

It may make more sense to leave this as a more "generic" emulator tag and to create [android-emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-emulator). Even so, I expect to get a lot of cross-pollination.

Anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: `android-emulator` seems like it might not be a bad idea, even if `emulator` does continue to get misused sometimes. It could at least help cut back on that since it would be in the autocomplete suggestions for "emulator" (and rely less on people actually reading the wiki excerpts).

Comment: Seconded. Eldarerathis: Make it an answer? You have my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [android-emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-emulator) to house all of the questions related to the Android emulator  specifically, then retagged the questions that were about other kinds of emulation. I also re-worked the [emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulator) wiki/excerpt to make it clear that it's for non-Android emulators. If I missed any questions in the retagging, feel free to fix them up.